# Rails 6 how to redirect to previous search results (new to rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

*Problem statement*:
I'm currently implementing a simple rails app where one can search and enroll courses. So after routing to **/search**, a search engine(implemented by `form_with`) shows up, where I can type course name and select subject name to whitelist the courses. After I click the search button, it will route to the page where it displays all the search results as well as a enroll button after each course. And of course if I click the enroll button I will enroll the course. I have successfully implemented the above. Now what I want to achieve is to make the server redirect me to the previous search results after I successfully enrolled.

*What I tried*:
In the enroll action inside the enrollments_controller.rb, if successully enrolled, I redirct it to search path. Like the following:

```
def enroll
        @enrollment = Enrollment.new(user_id:current_user.id,course_id: params[:enroll_course_id])
        if @enrollment.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully Enrolled!"
            
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Oops Failed to Enroll..."
        end 
        redirect_to search_path
    end
```

But this won't redirect me to previous search results, but intead, a page where all courses in the database is displayed.

**Does anyone know how to fix this issue? In case you want to see more of my code, I attached them under:**
First, the do_search_controller.rb:

```
class DoSearchController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end 
    
    def display 
       
        if params[:subject_id].blank?
            @courses = Course.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
        else
            @courses = Subject.find_by(sub_id: params[:subject_id]).courses.where("name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%")
        end
    end 

end
```

Second, The routes.rb file:(only the last 4 lines are related)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories
  resources :subjects
  resources :courses
  resources :instructors
  resources :users
  root 'welcome#index'
  get '/signup', to:'users#new'
  get '/dashboard', to:'users#show'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/search', to: 'do_search#new'
  get '/display', to: 'do_search#display'
 
  get '/enroll', to: 'enrollments#enroll'
  delete '/drop', to: 'enrollments#drop'
  
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to wrong path.

Redirect to `display_path` instead of `search_path`
and also you need to pass search `params` to display previous results

for this purpose you can also save user's last search in `session` or keep passing this in `params`.